# Exposing a property as readonly

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm writing framework and want to expose certain internal property as readonly.
So I added a readonly property in the header and 
synthesize it manually like this.

```
-(NSMutableURLRequest*) readonlyRequest {

    return [self.request copy];
}
```

The caller gets a copy which can still be mutated, but doesn't affect the internal property. 
Is this the right way to do? Or are there some other better alternatives?

***The code is compiled for ARC, so no autorelease***

Comment: `copyRequest` would be a better name than `readonlyRequest`, as `copyRequest` doesn't imply that the returned object is immutable, while `readonlyRequest` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually incorrect. The caller will get an `NSURLRequest*`. You need to use `-mutableCopy` instead.

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)readonlyRequest {
    return [self.request mutableCopy];
}
```

Alternatively, you should declare this as just `NSURLRequest *` (which is probably better, unless you have some reason to think the caller needs a *mutable* request).

**Edit:** Removed the bit about `autorelease` because the question was updated to indicate this is ARC.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if it's read only you would return a non mutable copy.
But yes that is the way.
And if you store a readonly property as an immutable object, since it's immutable you can just sent the object, the caller won't be able to modify your object.

Comment: readonly has nothing to do with mutability of the object type.

Comment: @KevinBallard exactly, but if you got a NSString that is readonly, you can just do : `return thatString;` No one is able to change it and you save yourself a copy.

Comment: Sure, but it looks like the OP has an `NSMutableURLRequest*` internally.

Comment: @KevinBallard the object can store the variable in any way it like it, that doesn't have to reflect the property, and some times it's better that both are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if conceptually it makes sense to have a mutableCopy in a readonly property. Maybe someone could give some examples of when it does to fill in some gaps in my thinking?

- I can't do a comparison without wondering if the object I have has been mutated since I received it
- If I receive an object from a class that I can mutate I generally assume I am mutating the instance in the class not a copy. This will likely lead to me doing some head scratching until I look closer at the header file to see what's going on - this of course is not as relevant in this case as you include `readonly` in the `@property` name, which is often not the case.

Comment: Precisely! That's why I named the property as readonlyRequest.

Comment: But the property should be declare as NSURLRequest, you don't have the obligation to have the exposed property the same type as the variable you are storing, in fact you don't even need a variable to back up a property.

Answer (score 1):

I think semantically it is weird to get back a mutable result from a read-only property.  The implication of read-only is the class not wanting the object changed, yet you are given an object where seemingly you can do so - even if behind the scenes it's really a copy it's not something expected.

Instead of a property I would make that just an accessor method like `mutableCopyOfMyData`, something that is clearer as to intent for the user to modify the result as they will.